# Angular 2 Losing Data within Observable Subscription

Tags: entity-framework, angular, asp.net-core, angular2-http, asp.net-core-webapi

In my application, I have a Web API controller which should be adding an entity of type "Source" to my DB, then returning the created Source. Source contains a list/collection of "SourceFields", which are themselves made up of a number of fields. Source also inherits from a base entity which I use for change tracking, and which contains fields like date created, date modified, etc.

Using Postman, I've tested my API and verified that it properly returns when I post a Source, and it includes all of objects that are created. However, when I use Angular 2 HTTP with RxJS Observables to post, the value which is returned has dropped all of the base entity fields, as well as the sourcefields. I use a Source class in Angular 2 to do operations, but I don't use it anywhere in the calls, so I don't think it's being typecasted or coerced? The only way I've gotten the source response to return properly (i.e. including the base entity properties) is if I set sourcefields to null in the API POST method.

This dataservice does work perfectly with simple entities. For example, I have a client entity that doesn't contain a collection like sourcefields, and it returns the base entity fields just fine.

Any ideas?

My API POST method:

```
        // POST api/Sources
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Source source)
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            dbContext.Sources.Add(source);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            //Hack to get source to return properly
            //source.SourceFields = null;
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetSource", new { id = source.SourceId }, source);
        }
```

Angular 2 Dataservice method:

```
public Add (action: string, itemToAdd: any): Observable<any> {
        var toAdd = JSON.stringify(itemToAdd);
        return this._http.post(this.actionUrl + action, toAdd, { headers: this.headers })
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error'));
    }
```

The place I'm subscribing to the dataservice:

```
this.addEditSource.sourceFields = this.sourceFields;
            this._dataService.Add('Sources', this.addEditSource).subscribe(source => {
                this.sources.push(source)
            },
                error => console.log(error));
```

If anyone wants to see my entity models or anything I can add them.